# Use Requirejs to dynamically load Knockout AMD template & modules asynchronously facing race condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js, requirejs, amd

I'm using Knockout, Require and [knockout-amd-helpers](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers) in my app.

I want to load models dynamically inside an `Knockout initialize` function which will be called many times, since I don't know what the models, figured this might be a more efficient way to dynamically load rather than load all models at once. See code below:

```
ko.utils.extend(ModelA.prototype.initialize = function(data, parent) {

...

require(['model/Pretag' + ko.unwrap( data.code )], function(Role){ 
    roleInstance = new Role(parent);
    roleInstance.initialize(data.properties);

    ....

    self.roleObservable( roleInstance );
}

...
})
```

**The Problem**: with this approach is, often times, I will run into race condition from the template's inline JS code since the `roleInstance.initialize(data.properties);` has yet to finish initialize.

Is there anyway to enforce multiple `require([..],function(){})` load asynchronously before the template start to execute any inline JS calls ?

**Update**: inline JS code inside the templates are as follow:

```
<li>Type: (<span data-bind="text: getObject('CODE').getProperties().STATIC_TYPE"></span>)</li>
```

This will throw an error, since `getObject('CODE').getProperties()` is undefined because `getObject('CODE')` has yet to finish initialize

The list is included by an inline ko template below.

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'template_contains_problem_inline_JS', foreach: people } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: can you describe the "inline JS calls" a little more.  are you saying that bindings are failing, because data hasn't been loaded/created yet?  I don't understand your full structure, but you might be able to use a `loading` observable and set it to `true` when you are done. Otherwise, possibly you could use the `module` binding from `amd-helpers` to load that module/section of your binding.

Comment: Thanks @RPNiemeyer I've included more example how the inline JS reside inside the app. Hope that can provide you a better understanding of my issue !

Also, I'm not sure what `loading` observable you're referring. Do you have an example ?

Comment: It seem in this case, that you could potentially use the `module` binding with a template (or inline template).  Otherwise, a good strategy is to use an observable and when your module loads, populate the observable with your module.  Then, you can use an `if`, `with`, or `template` binding to prevent any rendering until the module is loaded.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Good point ! Will give those a try, Thanks again @RPNiemeyer !